# html is working but javascript is not working in android version 4.4

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

I have a webview and I've loaded the html in that webview from assets. the html contains some javascript. I've also enabled `settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` in activity.

Javascript is working perfectly in other phones but I tested the app in android version 4.4 and html is loaded properly but javascript functions is not working there, what should i do to run javascript in android 4.4?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this :

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Also make sure your chrome browser is updated i know its not relevant but it cause problem many times atleast in my cast when i was using webview